# Not able to write the wildcard query for ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, match, wildcard

I am facing an issue using the wildcard. Whenever I try to find a data using wildcard, it is returning an error

Data Set looks like the following in ES:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 1000,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "accounts",
            "_type": "data",
            "_id": "25",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "account_number": 25,
               "balance": 40540,
               "firstname": "Virginia",
               "lastname": "Ayala",
               "age": 39,
               "gender": "F",
               "address": "171 Putnam Avenue",
               "employer": "Filodyne",
               "email": "virginiaayala@filodyne.com",
               "city": "Nicholson",
               "state": "PA"
            }
         }
```

And I use the below query:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query":{       
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" :
          {
            "match":{
            "wildcard":{"lastname" : "Aya*" }
            }
          }      
        }
      }
    }
    }
}
```

But it's throwing the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "query_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[match] query does not support [lastname]",
            "index": "accounts",
            "line": 9,
            "col": 25
         }
```

I have tried without the match instance using only the wildcard in the query , but still I cannot get the data. The search here is successful but the data is not returned.

Without Match Query:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query":{       
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" :
          {
            "wildcard":{"lastname" : "Aya*" }
          }      
        }
      }
    }
    }
}
```

Please help me understand how I should device the query. I have to use this query string in JAVA API as well. So, any advice on that front would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your `lastname` field is probably `analyzed` and thus the token that was indexed is `ayala` and not `Ayala`. So since `wildcard` queries are not analyzed you need to specify the search term in lowercase:

Try this:

```
POST /_search
{
    "query":{       
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" :
          {
            "wildcard":{"lastname" : "aya*" }
          }      
        }
      }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows results for items that don't match.

Comment: @OliverDixon Can you be more precise? maybe create a new question with your own use case

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "lastname": "aya*"
    }
  }
}
```

I had wasted many hours until I read this online:

> ...if you search a not_analyzed field and use wildcards, you MUST NOT
> include any capital letters in your query...

The whole time it was not working because I was searching for e.g. `Aya*`. Soon as I converted it to lower case `aya*` it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Searching with lower case also solved my problem. I was wondering why wildcard query worked for some fields and for some not...